# GoogleBigQuery "unable to find table" / Facebook Ads Integration through StitchData

Tags: facebook-graph-api, google-bigquery

I am a non-technical profile.

I am using Stitch Data in order to feed data from various sources (my website's data warehouse, FB ads, Adwords, etc.) into Google Big Query.

I had no issue feeding my data warehouse (mariaDB) into Big Query.

I followed the same method to fetch the data from FB ads.

Although my dataset (fb_ads) appears correctly on Google BigQuery with the related tables (ads, adsets, campaigns), cf image below,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4w7O.jpg)
I get an error message on the top of the screen "unable to find table: "dark-alloy-xxxxxx:fb_ads.ads"

I don't understand why. Any clue?

Thanks a lot,

Vincent

Comment: Please provide more details about the error.  For instance type of the HTTP code in [1](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors). More details can help to resolve the issue faster.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling adblock or accessing BQ in a clean browser without extensions. I had the same problem due to AdBlock blocking elements containing "ads".

Inspecting the error message using F12 in chrome might also clarify a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Either the table got deprecated or there was an internal issue on the BigQuery site.